# What does this mean: "the people who seem to defy the natural laws"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I was watching a speech on youtube and I guess I heard Darren Hardy said the following:

> I know you know those people who just seem to defy the natural laws 
>       of how the universe works.

I really have no idea what he means by **people who defy the natural laws of how the universe works**.

I thought this refers to people who have superpower that make the universe work for them and not simply obey the universe. Of course I might be wrong so I need a clearer phrase to translate it.

Comment: It could mean several things. Please provide a fuller context.

Comment: You could describe them as being immune to Murphy's law.

Comment: If you are trying to translate it,  you might look for words like "always unhindered by impossible situations"

Comment: Have voted to close as unclear.  Please post a link to a speech with this sentence in it, and provide a timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

> I really have no idea what he means by people who defy the natural laws of how he universe works

This is something you often see in cartoons or comics. There is one character, blissfully unaware of the dangers around him, who by all means should have gotten himself killed by now, but he keeps on survivng.
Not because he *intentionally* saves himself, but because of dumb luck.

That is what is meant. "Defying natural law" in this context mean "surviving a statistically unlikely survival chance, for no reason other than luck".

From the point of view of the villain, the hero is often one of these characters. The villain went to extensive measures to kill this hero, yet here he is AGAIN!? How is he doing this!? 
However, we (the viewer) know that the hero has survived through exceptional skill. In your example, it is implied that the person has survived by dumb luck rather than skill or conviction.

*Try as I might, I can't think of a good example at this time. And I'm sure there are tons of examples that I'm blanking on. Will update once I can think of one.*

**Edit**: The best I could think of: Michael Scott in The Office.

He is hilariously unskilled, petty, and rude (though he isn't malevolent). Across the series, there have been **hundreds** of reasons why he should have been fired or demoted (every reason being a good reason by itself). But this does not happen. Michael, through whatever dumb luck he has stumbled on, manages to stay in his job for as long as he wants the job.

A real person would have been fired after his first few racist comments. But no, not Michael. He **seemingly defies the rules of employment** and manages to evade full punishment for his mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

***Superhuman*** according to [Ref.](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/superhuman)

> 1. above or beyond what is human; having a higher nature or greater powers than humans have:  a superhuman being.
> 2. exceeding ordinary human power, achievement, experience, etc.:  a superhuman effort.